# Merge predict_proba with X_test results in NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In my classification problem, y='late_or_ahead'. Value of 1 means ahead. Value of 0 means late.

log_reg.predict_proba(X_test)
results in

```
array([[0.92537486, 0.07462514],
   [0.24936417, 0.75063583],
   [0.6222988 , 0.3777012 ],
   [0.29020199, 0.70979801],
    ....
   [0.93961168, 0.06038832]]
```

input: `log_reg.classes_` returns `array([0,1])`
If I get it correctly, it means that the left part of the array means probability of Y=0,
and right part of the array means probability of Y=1. Please correct me if I'm wrong in this regard.

With that assumption:

```
proba = pd.DataFrame(log_reg.predict_proba(X_test)) #convert array to dataframe
proba.columns = ['probability_late','probability_ahead']
proba


   probability_late probability_ahead
0   0.925375           0.074625
1   0.249364           0.750636
2   0.622299           0.377701
3   0.290202           0.709798
4   0.939612           0.060388
... ... ...
```

Now, when I combine these 2 columns (probability_late and probability_ahead) with X_test using the code below:

```
proba.reset_index(drop=True)
test_with_proba=X_test
test_with_proba.reset_index(drop=True)
test_with_proba['probability_late']=proba['probability_late']
test_with_proba['probability_ahead']=proba['probability_ahead']
test_with_proba[['probability_late','probability_ahead']]
```

that results in the following:

```
367 NaN            NaN
219 NaN            NaN
72  0.167852    0.832148
55  0.338693    0.661307
371 NaN            NaN
... ... ...
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: because of index.  it assign value to test_with_proba if index of test_with_proba matches with the proba. The assigment is purely on the row where the indices matches. That's why you are getting nan

Comment: sorry, i dont quite get you. how to solve it?

Comment: check my answer I have explain.

Comment: you didn't assign back  should be `test_with_proba  = test_with_proba.reset_index(drop=True)` or use `test_with_proba.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` --> `inplace=True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say you have:

**df1:**

```
    a   b
1   2   3
4   2   5
```

---

**df2:**

```
    a   b
1   6   3
5   2   8
```

---

```
df1['c'] = df2['a']
```

---

**df1:**

```
    a   b   c
1   2   3   6.0
4   2   5   NaN
```

---

as you can see there is (left join) when you are doing the assignment.

`df1` has indices `[1,4]` but `df2` has indices `[1,5]`

while assigning only index 1(of df1) is getting matches to that of df2 index.

So the index 4 will have NaN value.

#### So how to tackle this problem??

just reset the index by using `.reset_index(drop=True)`

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
df1['c'] = df2['a']
```

---

**df1:**

```
    a   b   c
0   2   3   6
1   2   5   2
```

Comment: thanks, but I still experienced the same error after implementing the change. Please refer to the edit I made..

Comment: Can you check the shape of those two dataframe? `test_with_proba` & `proba`

Comment: test_with_proba.shape ==> (89,15). proba.shape ==> (89,2)

Comment: it works now. thanks a lot and have a nice day.